# How would you suggest to in C# all users in GrpA and Grp B stored them in GrpAB using List<string>

Tags: c#

This is my current solution. Any better search algorithms?

```
   public void membersOfBothGroup(string groupA,string groupB)
        {
            List usersInGroupA = getGroupMembers(groupA);
            List usersInGroupB = getGroupMembers(groupB);
            List userInBothAB = new List();
            foreach (string userA in usersInGroupA)
            { 
                foreach(string userB in usersInGroupB)
                {
                    if (userA == userB)
                    {
                        userInBothAB.Add(userA);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example (since the datatype is `string`):

```
List<string> groupA = new List<string>() { "Moe", "Larry", "Curly" };
List<string> groupB = new List<string>() { "Moe", "Shemp", "CurlyJoe" };

var result = groupB.Intersect(groupA);
```

Output:

```
Moe
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
List<string> userinBothAB = usersInGroupA.Intersect(usersInGroupB);
```

Check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) for more details.